# Is it possible to return wether or not an image has loaded in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm (attempting) working on a function right now that will return whether or not the user has a gravatar. Javascript is limited to cross-site checks so this already feels kinda hacky. I'm writing this in django which I could use and write an API for... but I'd rather see if there is a way to do this client side instead of server side, but maybe that's the wrong mentality.

This is being written in an angular directive; but this is what I've came up with so far.

```
 $scope.hasAvatar = function(user) {

     if (user === undefined)
         return false;

     var url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + md5(user.email);

     var image = new Image();
     image.onload = function() {
         return true;
     }
     image.onerror = function() {
         return false;
     }
     image.src = url + "?d=404";
}
```

I'm still learning javascript. I know that because of the nature of javascript it doesn't wait to call the onload or onerror, it simply completes the function, which defaults to false.

Am I barking up the wrong tree trying to solve it this way? or is it possible to do with callbacks or promises? I really appreciate the help.

Comment: you should use angular's `$q` to return a promise.

Comment: Are you binding `hasAvatar` call in the view? Why dont you just bind it to a  property on the scope and use promise resolution (else you would need scope.$apply())

Comment: How are you calling it?  If user was null it would return false.

Comment: Yes it's being binded in the template.

Comment: assume user is not null, I've checked that.

Comment: Can you explain this   `it simply completes the function`

Comment: if a function had no return statement in it, wouldn't it default return false?

Comment: Well the image will try to load a 404'd image. therefore it wont be able to load and call error.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but are the onload and error callbacks expected to do something? Perhaps that's why Daniel suggests using a promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this with a promise since image loading is async:

```
$scope.hasAvatar = function(user) {
    var dfd = $q.defer();
    if (user === undefined)
       return $q.when(false);

    var url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + md5(user.email);

    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
       dfd.resolve(true);
    }
    image.onerror = function() {
       dfd.resolve(false);
    }
    image.src = url + "?d=404";
    return dfd.promise;
}
```

Then you call it like this

```
$scope.hasAvatar(user).then(function(hasAvatar) {
   // logic here. perhaps bind to showAvatar
   $scope.showAvatar = hasAvatar;
});
$scope.showAvatar = false;
```

Comment: not if it is bound directly to the view. But partly right, since it needs digest cycle involvement as image async events are outside ang world.

Comment: How does this help anything ?

Comment: @nix it gets it back into the digest cycle.

Comment: Problematic because I'm working with an html and ng-ifs, but I think this will help me move forward, I will play around with this for a bit.

Comment: @RalphEmerson async can be challenging - you have to think differently.

Comment: I think your solution works. I just have a lot to learn. I have it set up, but for some reason the only thing that matters is the check whether or not user is defined.

I know user is undefined for the first few seconds, but then later becomes defined as angular does it magic. But I have no idea how to regulate that, or wait for user to become defined, I'm sure i'm doing 108 things wrong. 

probably need to learn more about angular directives and links and watches and all these buzz words before I come back to this...